# Store C++ maps by value

Tags: c++, dictionary

Is it possible to store pairs such as  ordered by value in a map. Therefore finding the min and max element would be very cheap for me. I know in gnu libstdc++, map is implemented by using a RB-tree, but couldn't figure out how to store elements by ordered by value. I don't want to exchange keys with values, because my values don't have to be unique.

Note: I know about max_element and min_element functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `std::multiset`, if you only need your values. Example:

```
#include <set>
#include <map>

int main(){
  typedef std::map<int,double> your_map_type;
  your_map_type your_map;
  // populate your_map
  std::multiset<double> your_values;
  for(your_map_type::const_iterator it = your_map.begin(); it != your_map.end(); ++it){
    your_values.insert(it->second);
  }
}
```

Comment: or a multimap with value as the key.

Comment: are sets implemented as RB tree as well?

Comment: Yes. As such, look-up will be O(log n) and ordering will be strict-weak.

Comment: um .. your code doesn't compile. `multiset` doesn't have `operator[]` and even if it did, the type of `*it` is `std::pair<int, double>`, not `double`

Comment: @Fiktik: Geh, the example was coded with map in mind... gonna edit, thanks for the pointer.